# Issue with displaying lines and labels when freezing loop for gganimate chart

Tags: r, ggplot2, gganimate

I have the following dataset in R

```
data <- structure(list(date = structure(c(19556, 19557, 19558, 19561, 
19563, 19556, 19557, 19558, 19561, 19563, 19556, 19557, 19558, 
19561, 19563, 19556, 19557, 19558, 19561, 19563, 19556, 19557, 
19558, 19561, 19563), class = "Date"), Currency = c("BRL=X", 
"BRL=X", "BRL=X", "BRL=X", "BRL=X", "CNY=X", "CNY=X", "CNY=X", 
"CNY=X", "CNY=X", "INR=X", "INR=X", "INR=X", "INR=X", "INR=X", 
"RUB=X", "RUB=X", "RUB=X", "RUB=X", "RUB=X", "ZAR=X", "ZAR=X", 
"ZAR=X", "ZAR=X", "ZAR=X"), Value = c(0.0728283484445535, -0.330853035270251, 
-0.185196338381155, -0.59095144482415, -1.42536190678508, 0.121327281222205, 
0.771207935608831, 0.0822791148568092, 0.101803198039518, -0.422560743106815, 
0.0168185542960497, 0.000120863021479956, 0.0253440458877874, 
-0.086881918129611, -0.233479466023445, 0.436123047805403, 1.48504054900642, 
-0.557576741878718, -0.115936134798933, -0.410514833768572, -0.864034124436708, 
-1.03512202608551, -0.612038284146266, -0.444506775404796, -2.34736750187213
)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-25L))
```

I'm using `data` to create an animated chart using `gganimate`. For some odd reason, when the loop ends it removes the `geom_line` and `geom_text` for the last day in my dataframe (with the exception of the purple line (`ZAR=X`) which happens to be the last variable in my dataset). Is there any way to fix this and freeze the loop of my animated chart on the last day of my dataset for each variable?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(gganimate)

cum_fx <- data %>% {
    ggplot(., aes(date, Value, col = Currency)) +
      geom_line() +
      geom_text(aes(x = date, label = sprintf("%.2f", Value), group = Currency), hjust = 0,show.legend = F,fontface='bold',color='#16161E') +
      transition_reveal(date) 
}

animate(cum_fx, height = 7, 
        width = 15, units = "in", res = 150, renderer = gifski_renderer(loop = FALSE))

anim_save("fx.gif")
```

[image]

Comment: It seems to work for me ok with gganimate 1.0.7.

Comment: Thanks @JonSpring , I just tried it with 1.0.7 and it works for me as well. I will raise this with the package developers to find out what the issue is with 1.0.8